# JSON_EXTRACT for mutliple values problem (Matching a string in a form of integer array to integer using MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, mysql-json

table1:

```
id  languages
2   ["2"]   
3   ["1"]   
9   ["1","2"]
```

"languages" field is a varchar(255).

Table2:

```
language_id name
1           English
2           Japanese
```

"language_id" is int(11).

I want output like one of the following:

Desired Output 1:

```
id  languages  name
2   ["2"]      ["Japanese"]
3   ["1"]      ["English"]
9   ["1","2"]  ["English", "Japanese"]
```

OR

Desired Output 2:

```
id  languages  name
2   ["2"]      Japanese
3   ["1"]      English
9   ["1","2"]  English, Japanese
```

I tried the following query, which only gets close:

```
SELECT t2.name, r.*
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.language_id=CAST(json_extract(t1.languages, '$[0]') AS UNSIGNED);
```

The output of the above query:

```
id  languages  name
2   ["2"]      Japanese
3   ["1"]      English
9   ["1","2"]  English
```

The second part of the languages array is omitted in a "name" field.

How can I output like either one of Desired Output 1 or 2?

Comment: Use `JSON_TABLE()` to conver the arrays to tables. Then you can join these properly.

Comment: This is why putting JSON in SQL tables is a bad idea. Normalize your tables and it will be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON_TABLE()` to split the array into rows. You can then join with this to get all the names, and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine them into a comma-delimited string.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.languages, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS names
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN JSON_TABLE(languages, 
                "$[*]" columns (language VARCHAR(9) PATH "$")) AS t1_json
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.language_id = t1_json.language
GROUP BY t1.id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mKhSiirQPsFrv2ST7u6xeF/0)